# java hibernate - duplicate column with InheritanceType.JOINED

Tags: java, hibernate, joined-subclass

I want to have superclass and subclass stored in database with InheritanceType.JOINED. But everytime I try to do that, I get an error - `Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.inqool.personalpro.entity.QuestionAlgorithm column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`
here are my entities:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Question implements Serializable {

    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    ...
}

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
public class QuestionAlgorithm extends Question {

    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    ...
}
```

When I remove field 'id' from subclass, I get this error: `Could not locate table which owns column [id] referenced in order-by mapping`

any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the version of hibernate. In 4.1.7, this is bugged. I changed version to 4.1.4, and everything is working